# Jquery Want to retrieve value and print it

Tags: jquery, onchange

I want to select change: replace the value in #yourDiscount with discount='' of each option

```
<select name='purchase'>
<option value='100
' discount='95.05'>100
 testów/ 1,045.50 PLN</option>
<option value='500
' discount='567.39' selected>500
 testów/ 4,350.00 PLN</option>
<option value='1000
' discount='1,416.67'>1000
 testów/ 8,500.00 PLN</option>
<option value='2500
' discount='4,000.00'>2500
 testów/ 20,000.00 PLN</option>
<option value='10000' discount='13,846.15'>10000 testów/ 60,000.00 PLN</option>
<option>Inna ilość...</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class='l' style='color:green;margin-top:3px'>&nbsp; <b>i Rabat: <span id='yourDiscount'>567.39</span> PLN</b></div>
```

Any Suggestions how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get the attr('discount') of the option in the on('change'... event, something like this

```
  $('select[name="purchase"]').on('change', function(){
   var a = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('discount');
   $('#yourDiscount').text(a);
 });
```

[A fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/vfj48/2/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    $('#yourDiscount').text($(this).val());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<select id="dropPurpose" name='purchase'>
<option value='100
' discount='95.05'>100
 testów/ 1,045.50 PLN</option>
<option value='500
' discount='567.39' selected>500
 testów/ 4,350.00 PLN</option>
<option value='1000
' discount='1,416.67'>1000
 testów/ 8,500.00 PLN</option>
<option value='2500
' discount='4,000.00'>2500
 testów/ 20,000.00 PLN</option>
<option value='10000' discount='13,846.15'>10000 testów/ 60,000.00 PLN</option>
<option>Inna ilość...</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class='l' style='color:green;margin-top:3px'>&nbsp; <b>i Rabat: <span id='yourDiscount'>567.39</span> PLN</b></div>
```

**js:**

```
$(document).ready( function ()
{
  /* we are assigning change event handler for select box */
    /* it will run when selectbox options are changed */
    $('#dropPurpose').change(function()
    {
        /* setting currently changed option value to option variable */
        var option = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        /* setting input box value to selected option value */
        $('#yourDiscount').text($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Hope it should helpful for you. Please try and let me know.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jebasuthan/KF5Mw/)